# From a PDF that was created using LaTeX, how can I retrieve images that are drawn using LaTeX?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, latex

From a PDF that was created using LaTeX, how can I retrieve images that are drawn using LaTeX?

I have the c# code that retrieves images from a pdf. Unfortunately, it retrieves only images that were inserted into the PDF as JPEG, PNG etc..

This is the code I use for extracting images from a PDF.

```
class Image_Retriever
{
    public static void retrieve_image(String PDFSourcePath, String pdf_image_extraction_path)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDFSourcePath);
        PRStream pst;
        PdfImageObject pio;
        PdfObject po;
        int n = reader.XrefSize; //number of objects in pdf document
        FileStream fs = null;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                po = reader.GetPdfObject(i); //get the object at the index i in the objects collection
                if (po == null || !po.IsStream()) //object not found so continue
                    continue;
                pst = (PRStream)po; //cast object to stream
                PdfObject type = pst.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE); //get the object type
                //check if the object is the image type object
                if (type != null && type.ToString().Equals(PdfName.IMAGE.ToString()))
                {
                    pio = new PdfImageObject(pst); //get the image
                    fs = new FileStream(pdf_image_extraction_path + "image" + i + ".jpg", FileMode.Create);
                    //read bytes of image in to an array
                    byte[] imgdata = pio.GetImageAsBytes();
                    //write the bytes array to file
                    fs.Write(imgdata, 0, imgdata.Length);
                    fs.Flush();
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
    }
}
```

The above code does not retrieve LaTeX drawn images.

I heard that while preparing a pdf document with LaTeX, a user can draw images in the PDF using LaTeX. Is there code to retrieve those images also?

Comment: The problem is that if the images where drawn using tikz then it won't be easy to retrieve them because they are more or less directly vectorimages embedded in the pdf and getting these as an image would require you to render it yourself. Aside from having to distinguish what is text and graphic or even mixed. I really don't know much about the pdf-format but I know quite a bit about LaTeX and I would say it will be pretty hard to do that. Maybe I'll get corrected :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm a former developer of LaTeX2HTML.
As +SkryptX already said, accessing the objects at postscript level would require you to render the vector grafics yourself.
The best approach would be to let PS do the work and then clip the image from the output stream.
LaTeX2HTML used the tool pstoppm to convert the ps file into ppm (portable pixmap) images, then ppmtogif or ppmtopng.
Additionally to the ps file you need to know the bounding box size of the images you want to clip, this data can be extracted from the LaTeX source.

It's all a while ago now so I can't go into detail any more.
But you might want to check the l2h source code and comments yourself for the more technical issues.